# Animating exit of an element in React Motion (which receives these elements from a parent component)

Tags: reactjs, react-motion

**Background** I am trying to create a container for a collection of elements, each of which can be removed from the collection. When an element is removed, I want to animate its exit, and I am trying to achieve this using React Motion.

Here's a diagram of the above:

[image]

**Problem** I thought of using React Motion's `TransitionMotion` component, and got stuck trying to write a function that needs to be passed to it. Here is my — incorrect — code:

```
class Container extends Component {

  state = {
    elementStyles: {}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getElementStyles();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.getElementStyles();
  }

  getElementStyles() {
    if (!this.props.children.length || this.hasElementStyles()) return;

    // this assumes all elements passed to the container are of equal dimensions
    let firstChild = this.refs.scroller.firstChild;

    let elementStyles = {
      width: firstChild.offsetWidth,
      height: firstChild.offsetHeight,
      opacity: 1
    };

    this.setState({
      elementStyles
    });
  }


  hasElementStyles() {
    return !isEmpty(this.state.elementStyles); // lodash to the rescue
  }

  willLeave() {
    return { width: spring(0), height: spring(0), opacity: spring(0) }
  }

  getChildrenArray() {
    return Children.toArray(this.props.children); // that's React's util function
  }

  getModifiedChild(element, props) {
    if (!element) return;

    return React.cloneElement(
      element,
      {style: props.style}
    );
  }

  getInitialTransitionStyles() {
    let elements = this.getChildrenArray();
    let result = elements.map((element, index) => ({
      key: element.key,
      style: this.state.elementStyles
    }));
    return result;
  }

  render() {
    if (this.hasElementStyles()) {

      return (
        <TransitionMotion
          willLeave={this.willLeave}
          styles={this.getInitialTransitionStyles()}
        >
            { interpolatedStyles => {
              let children = this.getChildrenArray();
              return <div ref="scroller" className="container">
                { interpolatedStyles.map((style, index) => {
                    return this.getModifiedChild(children[index], style);
                  })
                }
              </div>
            }}
        </TransitionMotion>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div ref="scroller" className="container">
          { this.props.children }
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

}
```

Notice this line inside the map function in the TransitionMotion component: `return this.getModifiedChild(children[index], style)`. It is wrong, because once an element is removed from the collection, `this.props.children` will change, and indices of the `children` array will no longer correspond to the indices of the `styles` array calculated from those children.

So I what I need is either some clever way to track the `props.children` before and after an element has been removed from the collection (and I can't think of one; the best I could come up with was using a `find` function on the array `return this.getModifiedChild(children.find(child => child.key === style.key), style);`, but that will result in so many loops within loops I am scared even to think about it), or to use some completely different approach, which I am not aware of. Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution's delete animation slides the deleted item (and the rest of the "cards" in the row) horizontally left beneath the card on the left (using it's lower z-index).

The initial render sets up the < Motion/> tag and the cards display as a row.

Each card shares a delete button method which setStates the index of the array element and starts a timer that slices the array.  The setState triggers the render which animates the cards before the timer does the slice.

```html
class CardRow extends React.PureComponent {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cardToRemove: 99,
        };
    }

    findCard = (_id) => {
        return this.myArray.find((_card) => {
            return _card.id === _id;
        });
    };

    removeCardClick = (evt) => {
        const _card = this.findCard(evt.target.id);

        setTimeout(() => {  // wait for the render...
            this.myArray.splice(this.myArray.indexOf(_card), 1);
            this.setState({cardToRemove: 99});
        }, 200);

        this.setState({cardToRemove: this.myArray.indexOf(_card)});
    };

    render() {
        let items = this.myArray.map((item, index) => {

            let itemLeft = 200 * index;     // card width 200px
            if (this.state.cardToRemove <= index) {
                itemLeft = 200 * (index - 1);
            }

            // .cardContainer {position: fixed}
            return <div key={item.id}>
                <Motion style={{left: spring(itemLeft)}}>
                    {({left}) =>
                        <div className="cardContainer" style={{left: left}}>
                            <div className="card">
                                <button className="Button" id={item.id} onClick={this.removeCardClick}>Del</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </Motion>
            </div>;
        });

        items = items.reverse();

        return <div>
            {items}
        </div>;
    }
}
```

That's about it!  Thanks and enjoy,